# Custom Postype Query showing only 10 results should show 23 results

Tags: custom-post-types

This is the code I have currently on my development site. It only shows 10 results from custom post type "pacificheritage" but it should show 23 all together.

```
<?php                   
          global $post;
          $i=1;
          $args = array(
             'order' => 'ASC',
             'orderby' => 'post_date',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'post_type' => 'pacificheritage'
          );
      ?>    
      <?php if (have_posts()):?>
                <?php
                $list_of_posts = new WP_Query($args); 
                while ($list_of_posts->have_posts()):$list_of_posts->the_post();
                $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '');
                ?>
                <?php echo $post->ID; ?>
                <?php the_title(); ?><br/>
            <?php 
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query();
                endif; 
            ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add 'posts_per_page'=>'-1' to $args, so:

```
<?php                   
      global $post;
      $i=1;
      $args = array(
         'order' => 'ASC',
         'orderby' => 'post_date',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'post_type' => 'pacificheritage',
         'posts_per_page'=>'-1'
      );
  ?>    
  <?php if (have_posts()):?>
            <?php
            $list_of_posts = new WP_Query($args); 
            while ($list_of_posts->have_posts()):$list_of_posts->the_post();
            $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '');
            ?>
            <?php echo $post->ID; ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?><br/>
        <?php 
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
            endif; 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nats answer is great but for anyone who *cant see* an $args array one should look for the "posts_per_page" value in the wp_options database table. This is where all default options are set (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) if you don't output a custom set of $args.